# hide javascript dates in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

i have a form where the previous dates from today must be hidden in the first date picker and the second date picker must not show dates previous to the first selected date.

Date picker one
[image]

Date picker two
[image]

The form is working for the first row but i can't get the code to work for the other rows that follow when i "add" a new row.

Can anyone assist me with this Please?

here is my current code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function updateMinimumEndDate () 
  {
    var minimum = $('.DepartDate input').val();
    var minSplit = [];
    minSplit = minimum.split("/");
    var newMin = (minSplit[2]+"-"+minSplit[0]+"-"+minSplit[1]);
    $('.ReturnDate input').attr('min',newMin);
  }
  $('.DepartDate input').change(updateMinimumEndDate);

});
$(function() {

  $(document).ready(function () {

   var todaysDate = new Date(); 
    
    var year = todaysDate.getFullYear();       
    var month = ("0" + (todaysDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); 
    var day = ("0" + todaysDate.getDate()).slice(-2);   

    var minDate = (year +"-"+ month +"-"+ day);  
    
    $('.DepartDate input').attr('min',minDate);
   
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please add a js fiddle with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line

```
$('.DepartDate input').change(updateMinimumEndDate);
```

This needs to be in `docReady`. It also needs to use the jQuery function `.on` so that it will be triggered for new rows as they are added. I haven't checked this:

```
$('.DepartDate input').on('change', 'AnchorSelector', function() {updateMinimumEndDate())};
```

where `AnchorSelector` is a location which contains your form.